# fullcalendar cannot manage to delete last event in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/
User can create and delete events in the calendar. Relevant information about events are sent in a hidden field as JSON. This works when user is creating events but I didnt manage to make it correctly update the hidden field when user is deleting events. Here's the eventclick callback of my `$('#calendar').fullCalendar`

```
eventClick: function(event, element) {
      if(confirm('Voulez-vous supprimer cette dispo?')) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
        var array_all_events = [];
        var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        // console.log(all_events);
        $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
          // console.log(value.start["_d"]);
          // console.log(index);
           var day         = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd');
           var start_time  = moment(value.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = moment(value.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
             // var id          = value.unique_id["_i"];
             var slot        = {
                day: day,
                start_time: start_time,
                end_time: end_time,
              };
            array_all_events.push(slot);
            console.log(array_all_events.length);
            if (array_all_events.length == 0) {
              $("#dispo_array").val("");
            }
            else {
              $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
            }
        });
      }
    },
```

The script actually works when there is more than one hash in array_all_events but I cannot get it to update `#dispo_array` to an empty string when array_all_events is empty.

Comment: What is the type of element - `#dispo_array`? What element it is?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it is an `ìnput` field

Comment: So you are saying `$("#dispo_array").val("");` isn't workin?

Comment: exactly if there is no events in the calendar I do not wish to send anything through my input field

Comment: Ok.. So are you sure the control goes into `if statement` and not on else?

Comment: it seems like it goes in neither of them.... when I `console.log("hello")` in both statements, nothing is rendered...

Comment: You don't get any log in console from `console.log(array_all_events.length);` too?

Comment: I do but only if there are objects in the array, if there is nothing in the array I don't get 0 in the console, I get nothing

Comment: check `console.log(typeof(array_all_events));` in both the instances..

Comment: in else statement it renders `òbject`, in if statement nothing !

Comment: Ok then change the if condition to `if (typeof(array_all_events)=="" || typeof(array_all_events)==null) {`

Comment: ok I got it to work by getting if and else statement out of the each loop

Comment: cool.. You can post it as answer and accept it..

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by getting the if and else statement out of the each loop.

```
  eventClick: function(event, element) {
      if(confirm('Supprimer cette disponibilité?')) {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
        var array_all_events = [];
        var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        // console.log(all_events);
        $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
          // console.log(value.start["_d"]);
          // console.log(index);
           var day         = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd');
           var start_time  = moment(value.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = moment(value.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
             // var id          = value.unique_id["_i"];
             var slot        = {
                day: day,
                start_time: start_time,
                end_time: end_time,
              };
            array_all_events.push(slot);
            // console.log(array_all_events.length);
        });
       if (array_all_events.length == 0) {
          console.log("hello");
          $("#dispo_array").val("");
        }
        else {
          console.log(typeof(array_all_events));
          console.log(array_all_events.length);
          $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
        }
      }
    },
```